# How to get name of Field in Field declaration in c#

Tags: c#, .net-core

### What i do have:

I am declaring a large number of fields **most of which** are given its own name as **string** value. Something like

```cs
string ErrorCode0001 = "ErrorCode0001-C";
string ErrorCode0002 = "ErrorCode0002";
string ErrorCode0003 = "ErrorCode0003";
string ErrorCode0004 = "ErrorCode0004";
string ErrorCode0005 = "ErrorCode0005";
string ErrorCode0006 = "ErrorCode0001";
```

Now, if you put attention in the code above i had *a mistake* in `ErrorCode0006`, which is hard to notice.

The mistake above comes because i copy pasted the first **Field** declaration and then just modified the *suffix* number, missing the one in the last field.

### What i would like to have:

I would love to write something like

```
string ErrorCode0001 = $"{nameof(self)}-C";
string ErrorCode0002 = $"{nameof(self)}";
string ErrorCode0003 = $"{nameof(self)}";
string ErrorCode0004 = $"{nameof(self)}";
string ErrorCode0005 = $"{nameof(self)}";
string ErrorCode0006 = $"{nameof(self)}";
```

but i am not sure how to do this in **C#**.

Would love to see some clever suggestions here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to use [CallerMemberName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=net-5.0) attribute.

For this you define a method like:

```cs
private static String GetName([CallerMemberName] string fieldName = "")
            => fieldName;
```

which when called parameterless will return the name of the calling member (the field in your case!).

You use it like:

```cs
public static readonly string KPT1_0001 = $"{GetName()}-C";
public static readonly string KPT1_0002 = $"{GetName()}";
public static readonly string KPT1_0003 = $"{GetName()}";
public static readonly string KPT1_0004 = $"{GetName()}";
public static readonly string KPT1_0005 = $"{GetName()}";
public static readonly string KPT1_0006 = $"{GetName()}";

private static String GetName([CallerMemberName] string fieldName = "")
    => fieldName;
```